# Is there a smart way disable multiple divs in React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend

Consider the following code, in which multiple divs have to be disabled :

```
<Select disabled={isDisabled}>
 ...
</Select>
<Input disabled={isDisabled}>
 ...
</Input>
<Button disabled={isDisabled}>
 ...
</Button>
```

Is there any better way to do it, like

```
divsToDisable = [ select, input, button ];
 ...
func() // being a function that returns true or false based on the div that is calling it
{
...
}

<Select disabled={func()}>
 ...
</Select>
<Input disabled={func()}>
 ...
</Input>
<Button disabled={func()}>
 ...
</Button>
```

Comment: Is there any code logic to disable the elements? How do you decide which elements to add in your `divsToDisable` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to implement a form (guessing this because you are using inputs), you can characterize your inputs which you want to disable in a fieldset and set the **disabled** attribute of the fieldset to true this will result in disabling all the inputs inside a fieldset, a simple implementation in HTML.

[image]

your render function inside the component will look something like this:-

```
isDisabled = () =>{
    //disabling logic
}

render() {
  return (
    <form>
      <fieldset disabled={this.isDisabled()}>
        <legend>Personalia:</legend>
        Name: <input type="text" />
        Email: <input type="text" />
        Date of birth: <input type="text" />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  );
}
```

However if you donot require disabling of any form fields then use a wrapper around all the divs you want to disable and add a overlay on the divs to create the disable effect like [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_overlay.asp).

Answer (score 1):

Following your example:

```
divsToDisable = ['select','input','button'];
 ...
const isDisabled = (control) => divsToDisable.includes(control) // being a function that returns true or false based on the div that is calling it

<Select disabled={isDisabled('select')}> // true
 ...
</Select>
<Input disabled={isDisabled('input')}> // true
 ...
</Input>
<Button disabled={isDisabled('button')}> // true
 ...
</Button>
<TextArea disabled={isDisabled('textarea')}> // false
 ...
</TextArea>
```

**Live demo:**

```js
const divsToDisable = ['select','input','button'];


function App({ divsToDisable }) {

  const isDisabled = (control) => divsToDisable.includes(control);

  return (
    <div>
      <select disabled={isDisabled('select')}>
       <option>1</option>
       <option>2</option>
      </select><br /><br />
      <input type="text" disabled={isDisabled('input')} /><br /><br />
      <button disabled={isDisabled('button')}>Button</button><br /><br />
      <textarea disabled={isDisabled('textarea')}>
       Text Area
      </textarea>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App divsToDisable={divsToDisable}  />, document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```